# HighChart with multple JSON api data

Tags: json, highcharts

I am creating a linechart which  contain data from different JSON files, and the codes below is working but i'd like to know how may i group up these JSON data from different apis into one by a for each loop to shorter the codes.

```
//consider the vol1- vol10 looks like var vol1 = ['1123', '1234','5436'];
//because i have other method the convert it to an arrray
//Xvol1 is just something like Xvol1=["Jan","Feb","Mar"]

        $('#trendChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: false
        },
        xAxis: {        
            categories : Xvol1
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume',
            },
            min: 0
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: $(".profileName0").html(),

            data: vol1
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName1").html(),

            data: vol2
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName3").html(),

            data: vol3
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName2").html(),

            data: vol4
            },

            {
            name: $(".profileName4").html(),

            data: vol5
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName5").html(),
            data: vol6
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName6").html(),

            data: vol7
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName7").html(),
            data: vol8
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName8").html(),
            data: vol9
            },
            {
            name: $(".profileName9").html(),
            data: vol10
            },

]
    });
```

UPDATE 1:
I have tried but it doesn't seem like working.

```
var series = [];
                        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                         series.push({name: $('.profileName'+i+'"').html(),, data: vol[i]});
                        }


                        $('#trendChart').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'spline'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: false
                        },
                        xAxis: {        
                            categories : Xvol1
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Volume',
                            },
                            min: 0
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            spline: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        series: [series]
                                });
                            });
```

After i generate the data by a for loop successfully, i am now struggle about how to update the data, i tried to update it using `setData()` but seem it needs so adjustment in order to work.

```
                        var seriesData = [vol1, vol2, vol3, vol4, vol5, vol6 , vol7, vol8, vol9, vol10]; // add all the vols. I have used 2 for example


                        var series = [];
                        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                         series.push({name: names[i], data: seriesData[i]});
                        }

                        var trendChart12w = $('#trendChart').highcharts();
                        trendChart12w.series[0].setData(series);
```

Solution :

```
var dataCounting = $(".DataCount").last().html();
                        var seriesData = [vol1, vol2, vol3, vol4, vol5, vol6 , vol7, vol8, vol9, vol10]; // add all the vols. I have used 2 for example

                        var trendChart1y = $('#trendChart').highcharts();
                        trendChart1y.xAxis[0].setCategories(Xvol1);

                        for(i = 0; i < dataCounting; i++){
                        trendChart1y.series[i].setData(seriesData[i]);
                        }
```

Comment: Where's the `volX` data coming from? Can you make it into an array?

Comment: volX is just another array() for display category  on xAxis

Comment: I didn't express it correctly `volX` is a generic way to say `vol1, vol2 ,vol3....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can an array of the names like `var names = [all the names]` and an array of your data like `var seriesData = [vol1, vol2...]`
And then do

```
var series = [];
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
 series.push({name: names[i], data: seriesData[i]});
}
```

And then set this as your chart series.

**UPDATE**
Do this outside of your chart.

```
var seriesData = [vol1, vol2]; // add all the vols. I have used 2 for example
var names = [$(".profileName0").html(), $(".profileName1").html()] // add all names

var series = [];
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
 series.push({name: names[i], data: seriesData[i]});
}
```

And then in your chart, where you set the series, just do
`series: series`

Comment: And can you please make a example in details? i am quite new to highchart, am i declaring the for loop outside of the chart?

Comment: Yes you can also use for updating. Refring to series, (in loop), call the [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update).

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yeah, I was going to suggest that first but then I thought if one can do it before drawing the chart then why not.

Comment: On last question, how may i update the data? please see my update

Comment: @anson920520 the reason I didn't suggest setData and setCategories method was because you already had the data before drawing the chart. So you don't have to go through getting the chart and then adding it.
Also, in your solution you might want to change the method setData to `setData(vol1, false)`. If you don't supply the boolean it redraws the chart everytime you call the method. change it to false and call `trendChart1y.redraw()` after setting all the series.